# Oracle move online

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I have Oracle Release 12.1.0.2.0 and I need to reclaim wasted space due to data fragmentation. I have been told that I should use the instruction "MOVE ONLINE".

I tried the following but I'm getting errors:

```
ALTER TABLE table MOVE ONLINE UPDATE INDEXES
```

> ```
> ORA-14133 "ALTER TABLE MOVE cannot be combined with other operations"
> ```

and:

```
ALTER TABLE BFD_PRATICA MOVE ONLINE
```

> ```
> ORA-01735 "invalid ALTER TABLE option"
> ```

My tables are all non partitioned and non index-organized. I need to perform this operation with no down time.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Online table move is a 12.2 feature.

[Online Table Move](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/newft/new-features.html#GUID-BEEEA34D-3D81-4360-887C-A92BC711816D)

[About Moving a Table to a New Segment or Tablespace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-3DE67CF4-84C5-4AED-A8A3-B1D28D8EBEF6)

You can use `DBMS_REDEFINITION` or `SHRINK`.